# Error when trying to deploy Docusaurus in Git Pages

Tags: javascript, deployment, github-pages, docusaurus

I already configured the docusaurus.config.js file. And when executing the deploy with the command:

"GIT_USER=<GITHUB_USERNAME> yarn deploy" the error appears:

error Couldn't find a package.json file in "K:(repository directory on the local machine"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I tried to deploy the Docusaurus project on GitHub Pages and expected to see my project online

Comment: Could you provide the repository link?